# Unexpected behavior of CGImageDestinationAddImage that changes depending on my UIImage var in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uiimage, animated-gif, cgimage

I have a function that generates a gif with an array of UIImages. The image array size is 31, but I set the capacity to 15 because I only use select images.

Ultimately, the problem I'm having is that when I use a function to resize a CGImage, and use that as the image in CGImageDestinationAddImage, the resulting gif is the photos I sent in the time before, instead of the photos I sent through the function this time. I have no idea how this can happen, since the resulting gif can still generate of what image array I used the time before even if I closed out of the app.

Below is the basic generateGIF and imageWithImage functions, and then I'll show different things I've tried the results I got.

```
func generateGIF(photos: [UIImage], filename: String) -> Bool {

    let documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let path = documentsDirectoryPath.appending(filename)

    let fileProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount as String: 0]]

    var gifProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String: 0.1]] // actual speed is 0.2

    gifProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality as String: 0.1]]

    let cfURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path) as CFURL

    let imageCapacity = 15

    if let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(cfURL, kUTTypeGIF, imageCapacity, nil) {

        CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, fileProperties as CFDictionary?)

        var inc:Int = 0

        for _ in 0..<imageCapacity { // actual photos.count is 31
            // I create 'photo' to determine what new size I should
            // use, for my own convenience, not included in this code
            let photo = photos[inc]

            let width:CGFloat = 200

            let smallerPhoto = imageWithImage(image:photos[inc], newWidth:width)

            CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, smallerPhoto.cgImage!, gifProperties as CFDictionary?)

            inc += 2
        }

    }
    // do something with gif, i.e. save to photo albums or display
    // in my case I save using path as a URL
}

func imageWithImage(image:UIImage, newWidth:CGFloat) -> UIImage{
    let scale = newWidth / image.size.width
    let newHeight = image.size.height * scale
    let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)

    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: newSize)

    let image = renderer.image { (context) in
        image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: newSize))
    }
    return image
}
```

As I explained, the resulting gif using the code above will make a gif out of the images I captured the time before.

If I use the 'photo' in CGImageDestinationAddImage, the resulting gif is what I'd expect, and not what I created last time, but the CGImages are not resized because I did not pass them through that function.

```
CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, photo.cgImage!, gifProperties as CFDictionary?)
```

As an experiment, I defined smallerPhoto as 'photo', expecting it to copy over what I defined before, and used that with CGImageDestinationAddImage. Instead the resulting gif is what I is from the array of UIImages I sent to the function generateGIF function from the last time.

```
let smallerPhoto = photo
CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, smallerPhoto.cgImage!, gifProperties as CFDictionary?)
```

Alternatively, I tried defining smallerPhoto directly as the current array index in photos, and used it in CGImageDestinationAddImage. This gave me the correct set of images I passed into generateGIF. However, this skips resizing the CGImages, which I need to do.

```
let smallerPhoto = photos[inc]
CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, smallerPhoto.cgImage!, gifProperties as CFDictionary?)
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to finalize my image with CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination).

func generateGIF(photos: [UIImage], filename: String) -> Bool {

```
let documentsDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
let path = documentsDirectoryPath.appending(filename)

let fileProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount as String: 0]]

var gifProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime as String: 0.1]] // actual speed is 0.2

gifProperties = [kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary as String: [kCGImageDestinationLossyCompressionQuality as String: 0.1]]

let cfURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: path) as CFURL

let imageCapacity = 15

if let destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL(cfURL, kUTTypeGIF, imageCapacity, nil) {

    CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, fileProperties as CFDictionary?)

    var inc:Int = 0

    for _ in 0..<imageCapacity { // actual photos.count is 31
        // I create 'photo' to determine what new size I should
        // use, for my own convenience, not included in this code
        let photo = photos[inc]

        let width:CGFloat = 200

        let smallerPhoto = imageWithImage(image:photos[inc], newWidth:width)

        CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, smallerPhoto.cgImage!, gifProperties as CFDictionary?)

        inc += 2
    }

}

let finalized:Bool = CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination)

if finalized {
   // do something with gif, i.e. save to photo albums or display
   // in my case I save using path as a URL
}

// return finalized boolean value
return finalized
```

}